# When to call super.onPause()?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am implementing Analytics in my android application, and I would like advice on when to call `super.onPause()`

```
if (mAnalyticsSession != null) {
    mAnalyticsSession.close();
    mAnalyticsSession.upload();
}

super.onPause();
```

What is the effect of calling `super.onPause()` after doing upload actions vs. before?

In general, when should one call `super.onPause()`?

Comment: Welcome to SO, don't forget to select a correct answer :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16925579/56285 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/9625920/56285

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only call `super.onPause()` in your own `Activity.onPause()` override.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Do your stuff, e.g. save your application state
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to override this if you don't need it. If you're going to override it, then do not make slow processes in here or you might get an ANR.

Comment: So you recommend calling super.onPause() first and then other actions?

Comment: ok.  I was just a bit concerned about putting them before super.onPause() but the analytics sdk guidelines said it needed to be before.

Comment: As indicated by @Bastami1982 below, super.onPause() should be called before any other code. The reference he mentions can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Comment: @bkurzius You're right. That's what the code in my answer shows and that's how I always do it.

Comment: @m0skit0 - i voted it down because your comment above says it "Doesn't really matter". But if you update your answer I'll be happy to vote it back up :-)

Comment: @bkurzius I already said in the comments that you're right and I'm wrong. My answer doesn't need any update since super.onPause() is called first.

Answer (score 20):

The selected answer is not correct, (I know this is an old question but for new readers here is the correct way: **Add your codes after Super.onPause or Super.OnStart ,...**
And here is an Android reference for your question(direct link is in comment):

> Quote from Activities:
>   Your implementation of these life-cycle methods must always call the superclass implementation before doing any work.

Comment: Here is the link to the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html