# Android implementation of lifecycle methods can call the superclass implementation after doing any work?

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

In the [Android documentation we have](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks):

> Note: Your implementation of these lifecycle methods must always call
>   the superclass implementation before doing any work...

But I have seen cases where the code is placed after the superclass method, especially for methods like onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy(), for example:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#ownreceiver_localbroadcastmanager

In both ways it works. So, what's the difference between putting the code before o after calling the superclass method? What's the correct way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Directly copied from CommonsWare's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9626268/931982). So better give him the upvote

> Methods you override that are part of component creation
>   (`onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()`, etc.), you should chain to
>   the superclass as the first statement, to ensure that Android has its
>   chance to do its work before you attempt to do something that relies
>   upon that work having been done.
>
> Methods you override that are part of component destruction
>   (`onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()`, etc.), you should do your
>   work first and chain to the superclass as the last thing. That way, in
>   case Android cleans up something that your work depends upon, you will
>   have done your work first.
>
> Methods that return something other than `void`
>   (`onCreateOptionsMenu()`, etc.), sometimes you chain to the superclass
>   in the return statement, assuming that you are not specifically doing
>   something that needs to force a particular return value.
>
> Everything else -- such as `onActivityResult()` -- is up to you, on
>   the whole. I tend to chain to the superclass as the first thing, but
>   unless you are running into problems, chaining later should be fine.

But if there is no dependancy, then call the superclass methods anywhere you want.

Answer (score 7):

When I interested about this problem, I found this rule:

```
during any kind of initialization, let the super class do their work first; 
during any kind of finalization, you do your work first
```

This is logical)

Answer (score 2):

When overriding any of the methods, you may need to call the superclass implementation. The rule of thumb is that during initialisation, you should always call the superclass first.

```
public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   // do work after super class function
   // setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
```

During de-initialisation, you should do the work first before calling the super class.

```
public void onPause() {
   // do work here first before super class function //LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
       super.onPause();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Java standards and best practices, the `super` call should go first. I believe the reason for this is that there may be work that needs to be done in a `super` that would cause problems in your code if you didn't do these first.

However, I have done work before calling `super` and haven't had any problems.

I don't have any framework examples but I have a `BaseActivity` class which `extends Activity` and all of my `Activities` extend `BaseActivity`. I have several methods that need to be implemented in these subclasses. If I don't make the call to `super` first then some variables don't get initialized that need to be so I would get `NPE`s