# What is logic behind before super.method or after super.method in android?

Tags: android, methods, super

Hello everyone i want to ask what is difference between if i something write before super.onDestroyView(); and after super.onDestroyView(); see example below

> Remove fragment before super.ondestoryview();

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {

        try {
            Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.mapviews));
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(fragment);
            ft.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

> Remove fragment after super.ondestoryview();

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        try {
            Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.mapviews));
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(fragment);
            ft.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: what this method will do if i write before super.ondestroyview and after super.ondestroyview

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/ndsrBsIchFc. read dianne hackborn's comment

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android implementation of lifecycle methods can call the superclass implementation after doing any work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925579/android-implementation-of-lifecycle-methods-can-call-the-superclass-implementati)

Comment: thanks Eli Rising & Raghunandan both are help full

Answer (score 7):

If super was Fragment, than there is no difference how you do it, because Fragment's onDestroyView does nothing. But in some cases it matters.

As Dianne Hackborn said:

> general rule: during any kind of initialization, let the super class do their work first; during any kind of finalization, you do your work first

P.S. IMHO it's not a good solution to remove fragment from other Fragment's onDestroyView method. That's strange, I think you should find better place for managing your fragments...

Answer (score 0):

Helpful answer

**case 1:** if there is some code written in super.onDestroyView, then that code will be executed after the code you have written.

**case 2:** if there is some code written in super.onDestroyView, then that code will be executed first, then the code you have written will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for Fragment.java onDestroyView():

```
/**
 * Called when the view previously created by {@link #onCreateView} has
 * been detached from the fragment.  The next time the fragment needs
 * to be displayed, a new view will be created.  This is called
 * after {@link #onStop()} and before {@link #onDestroy()}.  It is called
 * <em>regardless</em> of whether {@link #onCreateView} returned a
 * non-null view.  Internally it is called after the view's state has
 * been saved but before it has been removed from its parent.
 */
@CallSuper
public void onDestroyView() {
    mCalled = true;
}
```

The important line of that documentation is:  `Internally it is called after the view's state has been saved but before it has been removed from its parent.`

If your `onDestroy()` method does not need any changes to views to be saved, then I think it doesn't matter when you call `super()`.

Comment: I'm trying to find the reason why that Boolean "mCalled" goes from true, to true, and then true...all the way down the life cycle.
true -> true -> true -> true, etc... ... ... unless it is set to false in-between phases, and is meant to tell the fragment whether a super was overwritten..., if this is not the case, it kinda makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should *generally* do its work after the originally intended work is done - the caveat here is if the work of the super changes the state of whatever you want to work with. That said, it does come down to a case by case basis - read the code of the super - sometimes those are already super-ing something else.

Answer (score 0):

onDestroy() of super should be called once u have done with your clean up handling. Its a good coding practice and cause for a less buggy programming.