# Back button is processed after activity destroy is called

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I'm trying to understand how it is possible. I have a crash which happens occasioanlly. Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'com.mycompany.myapp.fragments.timeline.TimelineFragmentView com.mycompany.myapp.injections.FragmentComponent.createTimelineFragmentView()' on a null object reference
    at com.mycompany.myapp.fragments.timeline.TimelineFragment.createView(TimelineFragment.java:28)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.fragments.timeline.TimelineFragment.createView(TimelineFragment.java:17)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.fragments.BaseFragment.onCreateView(BaseFragment.java:33)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.fragments.ScreenFlowBaseMenuFragment.onCreateView(ScreenFlowBaseMenuFragment.java:22)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:958)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1666)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:586)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:169)
    at com.mycomany.mayapp.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:125)
    at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2483)
    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2664)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2736)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:224)

    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
```

And `FragmentComponent` is nulled in the last line of the next method:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    backendResponseMonitor.stop();
    view.stop();

    Graph graph = (Graph) getApplication();
    graph.destroyFragmentComponent();
}
```

Since everything runs on UI thread then it looks like back button processing is performed after activity `onDestroy` called. Am I missing some concept of activity lifecycle?

**Don't keep activities** developer option flag is turned on

Comment: try with moving `super.onDestroy()` to be the last statment in the method.

Comment: Thanks! What is the cause of the crash? How moving the super call will help with crash?

Comment: `super.onDestroy();` will cleanup the `Activity`. check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625920/should-the-call-to-the-superclass-method-be-the-first-statement/9626268#9626268

Comment: Hense I agree with the comment about changing the order of calling super. I still can not understand what happens. My activity `onDestory` completely executed before `keyCode` is processed. So I don't see much difference to have in the start or end of the method

Comment: Look like you have an issue with the app flow, somehow `TimelineFragment.createView` is called on `Destroying` the `Fragment`s. do you keep a references to your `Fragment`s in the `AppContext` ?

Comment: I don't know for sure about leaks. The stacktrace starts from Android OS, so Android is invoking back button processing after activity should be destroyed

Answer (score 0):

`super.onDestroy();` calls the super class `onDestroy` method that clears all the references used in your activity. Hence you are getting null point exception. Just make your `onDestroy` as follows.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    backendResponseMonitor.stop();
    view.stop();

    Graph graph = (Graph) getApplication();
    graph.destroyFragmentComponent();

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: this is just another guy's comment you turned into your answer. not cool man :P

Comment: Am sorry man i didnt notice it. Started typing and then went off for a bit. Sorry Vucko and sorry JafarKhQ

Comment: I know bro, happens to me a lot also, I just open the post and forget about it for 5 min, when I'm back -> already answered and I hadn't noticed :D

Comment: It is not super that clears references. It is `graph.destoryFragmentComponent()` method